# How does this happen? About android task

Tags: android, task

I don't have 10 reputation to post images. What I want to ask is about the figure 4 in this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

I think this would never happen. Activity Y Declared with "singleTask", how can Activity X below Activity Y? Is this figure wrong?